# EhCache Performance on Tomcat Vs Websphere 7

Tags: performance, tomcat, jvm, websphere, ehcache

We are using EhCache in our Application to store 510 000 records.

We are observing significant amount of lag when deploying the application on IBM WAS 7 as compared to Embedded Tomcat of Spring boot. ( Both are hosted on local system and using JDK 6)

On Tomcat it is taking around 800-900 ms as compared to WAS 7 2000-2500 ms (Calculated on method level excluding network delay).

Could anyone help us understanding why there is a significant delay or help us optimizing WAS 7 performance

Comment: Very hard to give any advice with the limited information. When measuring, did you do enough operations to give the JIT of the JVM a chance to run? What's the link with Ehcache? What are the server configurations? And more ...

Comment: Louis , through Profiling tool , we have investigated till executeQuery method of EhCache. Lag in time is occuring at EHCache API only . What do you mean by  "did you do enough operations to give the JIT of the JVM a chance to run?"  please elaborate